# SSRS 2016 - Failure sending mail: The operation has timed out.Mail will not be resent

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016, ssrs-subscription

I am constantly getting the following error when sending out email subscriptions (data driven)

```
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
notification!WindowsService_5!2754!07/31/2018-10:12:22:: e ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription ec52efbe-63be-4b47-85e1-fa8f850d76ab: Failure sending mail: The operation has timed out.Mail will not be resent.
notification!WindowsService_5!2754!07/31/2018-10:12:22:: i INFO: Notification 8290464c-90d6-4e58-859e-33f4a4e24a74 completed.  Success: False, Status: Failure sending mail: The operation has timed out.Mail will not be resent., DeliveryExtension: Report Server Email, Report: Invoice, Attempt 0
emailextension!WindowsService_5!8c0!07/31/2018-10:12:33:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I don't think it's the report timing out as it runs fine for file share subscription without any errors.. Only about 60 - 70 emails are generated at any one time and more than 75% fail with the above error.. yet I have the same report doing over 400 for file share and they all work fine. (0 errors)

I've looked at report server settings and increased the session timeout value etc.. but hasn't made any difference..

I'm using SSRS 2016 (64 Bit) Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit)

I can't seem to find any sort of definitive pointers online.. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you pull the SMTP logs and find the offending addresses and see if they are valid?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I doubt it's the address.. if I run the subscription again.. it will fail on different set of addresses.. so it's not consistent.. hence me pulling my hair out!

Comment: Are you sure SMTP is correctly configured?

Comment: Yes it is, I have other data driven email subscriptions that have up to 10 or 15 emails and they seem to work fine.. I'm also wondering if it is possible to throttle down how many emails are sent out from a single subscription

Comment: In my case SMTP mail relay has been disallowed by the reporting server.  Allowing mail realay from the SSRS server again resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who come across this and wonder how to fix this issue..  I cannot believe this hasn't been suggested ANYWHERE!

Change the time out on the Dataset for the Data Driven subscription. This fixed the error I was encountering! So simple..

Mine was set at 30 seconds.. I changed this to 100 and it worked fine. but my report run in under 3 seconds per report..  changing this value to 0 make it not timeout. Not sure if that is a wise idea or not..